# Зависает запись на флэшку

Tags: flash-память

Есть флэшка SanDisk Cruzer Blade 16gb. Во время записи не больших файлов размером ~1gb проблем никаких нет, но как только пытаешь скинуть на нее файл больше начинается беда - запись зависает секунд на 20 с определенной периодичностью: то есть, если у нас есть фильм размером в 5gb, то запись его зависнет на ~1 - 1.5gb, ~3 - 3.5gb и ~5gb. При просмотре такого фильма на телевизоре запись на этих "зависших" моментах обрывается, и что бы посмотреть дальше приходится проматывать этот момент. При попытке загрузить файл на эту флэшку торрентом он просто зависает. Кто может подсказать, с чем может быть связана данная проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похожие проблемы возникали и с обычным внешним механическим хардом, пристёгнутым по USB 2.0. Большие файлы (несколько гигабайт, 5-6 примерно)резались просто при копировании вендами. Вылечилось переходом на Firewire, а затем на USB 3.0. Есть такое впечатление, что это именно из-за USB 2.0. Попробуйте поиграться в настройках BIOS скоростями USB 2.0. Но мне это не помогло.

Comment: Дело в том, что ранее такой проблемы не было. Был внешний винт, использовал для таких же целей, буквально пол года назад начались эти проблемы, на винте оказалось много битых секторов. Решил не мучиться, купил флэшку, проблема осталась.

Comment: Выкрутил в биосе скорость на максимум, отключил какой то там режим не правильного монтирования, поставил торрент фильм размером 6.3гб, на 24% зависло. Больше в биосе никаких опций касательно юсб не было. И как я говорил раньше - таких проблем не было, должны же они были по какой то причине появится.

Comment: Все-таки проблема была в кэшировании. Не знаю как и почему, но именно с ней. Так как винда не умеет полностью отключать кэш установил Total Commander, в настройках операции с файлами выбрал режим работы с большими файлами (кэш не используется) и все заработало. Файлы летят медленно, но долетают по адресу, так же в тотале есть отличная функция проверки файлов, что бы быть уверенным в записи. Так что, в который раз убеждаюсь, что виндовс с файлами работает не очень...

Comment: Спасибо! Я тоже всё время думал, что дело в вендовом кеше, но шеф решил просто купить новую железку, и потом уже я дальше копать не стал.

Comment: так же можно поступить в FAR: отключить "системная функция копирования"